# Edge detection - remove background

Tags: python, image, background, edge-detection

Would like to use edge detection on microscope images to make the background white.
This is the code i have so far, could this be useful?

code:

```py
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def simple_edge_detection(image): 
   edges_detected = cv2.Canny(image , 100, 200) 
   images = [image , edges_detected]
   location = [121, 122] 
   for loc, edge_image in zip(location, images): 
      plt.subplot(loc) 
      plt.imshow(edge_image, cmap='gray')
   cv2.imwrite('edge_detected.png', edges_detected)
   plt.savefig('edge_plot.png')
   plt.show()
   
img = cv2.imread('gay2.0.jpg', 0)
simple_edge_detection(img)
```

[result of the code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWkcC.png)

[result wished:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqVKb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Canny filter and binarize with a threshold sufficient to remove most of the background.

Remove the small blobs and detect those against the image borders (possibly fill their holes). These define a mask around the object of interest (don't worry about the green blob and orange lines in the picture).

You may add some preprocessing or postprocessing to remove the holders.

[image]